# Run UITest written within Framework

Tags: swift, cocoa, xctestcase, xcuitest

I am working on a framework which contains Visual Representation(UI) and I have written some UI tests into it but I am not able to run UITest written within framework.

Could anyone please guide me wether we can write UITest within framework or not?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try running in Test navigator where you find all the UI tests.

[image: Check this..It might help!!]